# Возврат view после ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Столкнулся с проблемой: при переходе по страницам через клавиши вперёд и назад браузера (Chrome), загружаемая страница распадается на код. Точнее сказать мне возвращается json объект, который я отдаю с сервера.(Надеюсь выразился понятно.)

Как работать с ajax в принципе понятно: отправил запрос, в ответ получил json строку и её отрисовал. Но когда идёт переход на предыдущую или следующую страницу, части success нет, поэтому и возвращается просто строка. Как её отрисовать? Может как-то можно повесить отрисовку через jquery при загрузке страницы?

Сайт написан на Laravel. Кусок кода, в котором я возвращаю json.

```
if(request()->ajax()) {
        $sections = $view->renderSections();

        return response()->json([
            'content' => $sections['content'],
            'modal' => $sections['modal'],
            'title' => $sections['title'],
            'materials' => $sections['content']
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Возвращается json строка? Что значит `части success нет`? Как принимаете данные на клиенте?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, возвращается json строка. Часть success - подрузумевал стандартный вызов $ajax(type: ..., data..., success (function ({тело функции}))) . Этой части нет как я понимаю когда осуществляется переход на предыдущую страницу. Как принимаются данные на клиенте - вот в этом и вопрос) Отрисовка клиента - на сервере формирую view и его возвращаю. В случае ajax запроса срабатывает код, который указан в вопросе.

Comment: смотрите `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Это оптимизация браузеров. В истории переходов сохраняются GET запросы на сервер. У меня была проблема при использовании в CPA с `vue-router`, где если было первональное открытие страницы - отдавался html, а если была навигация через `vue-router` - бэк отдавал `json`. Решено было только отправкой POST запросов

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Динамики у меня в проекте нет. Максим, Ваш ответ уже ближе к нужному (по моему ощущению). Сначала отдаётся страница в blade, а потом возвращается json.

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодится. Один из вариантов решения (правда не совсем корректный на мой взгляд) - это перегрузка всей страницы. На сервере использую jsonp. Почитайте, возможно решит Вашу проблему.

Answer (score 0):

можно ж использовать событие "popstate".
У меня была такая же проблема вот этим я и решал

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
    // Получаем URL текущей страницы
    var currentUrl = window.location.href;

    // Отправляем ajax-запрос на сервер для получения данных
    $.ajax({
        url: currentUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // Обновляем контент на странице
            $('body').html(data.content);

            // Обновляем заголовок страницы
            document.title = data.title;

            // Отображаем модальное окно
            $('#myModal').html(data.modal).modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```